# Random date between 2 given dates

Tags: scala, date, random

I want to calculate random date between 2 dates.

So I have this function:

```
  def calculateDates(from: LocalDate, until: LocalDate): Seq[LocalDate] =
  {
    val ld: LocalDate = new LocalDate()
    if (from.compareTo(until) > 1)
      return[]
    else
    return from :: calculateDates(from.plusDays(1), until)
  }
```

And my inputs:

```
01 Jan, 1970
01 Jan, 2015
```

So first I need to change my function to return only one date and second thing is how to convert my input into `LocalDate` object ?

Answer (score 12):

Rather than generating all of the dates between the two and randomly picking one, why not calculate the number of days between the two, pick a random number within that range, and add the days to the first date?

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.DAYS
import scala.util.Random

def random(from: LocalDate, to: LocalDate): LocalDate = {
    val diff = DAYS.between(from, to)
    val random = new Random(System.nanoTime) // You may want a different seed
    from.plusDays(random.nextInt(diff.toInt))
}

scala> val from = LocalDate.of(1970, 1, 1)
from: java.time.LocalDate = 1970-01-01

scala> val to = LocalDate.of(2015, 1, 1)
to: java.time.LocalDate = 2015-01-01

scala> random(from, to)
res31: java.time.LocalDate = 2010-09-13
```

Comment: looks fine, can i automatically obtain the date format ? (dd MMM, yyyy / yyyy-MMM-dd...)

Answer (score 3):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, [`scala.util.Random`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/util/Random$.html) provides [`between(minInclusive: Long, maxExclusive: Long)`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/util/Random.html#between(minInclusive:Long,maxExclusive:Long):Long) which combined with [`LocalDate::toEpochDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#toEpochDay--):

```
import scala.util.Random
import java.time.LocalDate

// val start = LocalDate.of(2019, 1, 20)
// val end   = LocalDate.of(2019, 2, 12)
LocalDate.ofEpochDay(Random.between(start.toEpochDay, end.toEpochDay))
// LocalDate = 2019-01-26
```

Note that the last date is excluded. In order to include it:

```
LocalDate.ofEpochDay(Random.between(start.toEpochDay, end.toEpochDay + 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
LocalDate.ofEpochDay(from.toEpochDay + Random.nextInt((to.toEpochDay - from.toEpochDay) toInt))
```